# Why Oracle OSB Business Service takes so much time to request external web service?

Tags: web-services, soa, osb

I'm using a business service to request an external web service but for some reason the BS is taking more than 20 seconds to get a response but the problem isn't form the remote web service, cause I tested it from SoapUI directly and it takes less than one second.

I'm not sure why this behavior is happening cause in the pipeline flow after the business service there is nothing more (I'm using Routing component in the pipeline), so I understand using the BS directly should be the same than using SoapUI to request the remote WS.

Here I'm requesting the external WS with SoapUI, and it shows the delay is one second or less:

[image: test soap ui]

But using the BS it takes up to 20 seconds:

[image: test business service]

I'm using exactly the same request in both cases, and sending the request to the same URL, and I'm getting the same response. Here is my BS configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<con:businessServiceEntry xmlns:con="http://xmlns.oracle.com/servicebus/business/config" xmlns:oper="http://xmlns.oracle.com/servicebus/business/operations">
    <con:coreEntry>
        <con1:binding type="SOAP" isSoap12="false" xsi:type="con:SoapBindingType" xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/services/bindings/config" xmlns:ser="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/services" xmlns:http="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports/http" xmlns:env="http://www.bea.com/wli/config/env" xmlns:tran="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:con1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/servicebus/business/config">
            <con:wsdl ref="wsdl/VerificarAlerta"/>
            <con:port>
                <con:name>wsRemoteService</con:name>
                <con:namespace>urn:https://remoteService.com/remote.php</con:namespace>
            </con:port>
            <con:WSI-compliant>false</con:WSI-compliant>
        </con1:binding>
        <oper:operations enabled="true">
            <oper:throttling enabled="false"/>
            <oper:resultCachingEnabled>true</oper:resultCachingEnabled>
        </oper:operations>
        <con:ws-policy xmlns:ser="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/services" xmlns:http="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports/http" xmlns:env="http://www.bea.com/wli/config/env" xmlns:tran="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ser:binding-mode>wsdl-policy-attachments</ser:binding-mode>
        </con:ws-policy>
    </con:coreEntry>
    <con:endpointConfig xmlns:ser="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/services" xmlns:http="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports/http" xmlns:env="http://www.bea.com/wli/config/env" xmlns:tran="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <tran:provider-id>http</tran:provider-id>
        <tran:inbound>false</tran:inbound>
        <tran:URI>
            <env:value>https://remoteService.com/remote.php</env:value>
        </tran:URI>
        <tran:outbound-properties>
            <tran:load-balancing-algorithm>round-robin</tran:load-balancing-algorithm>
            <tran:retry-count>5</tran:retry-count>
            <tran:retry-interval>5</tran:retry-interval>
            <tran:retry-application-errors>true</tran:retry-application-errors>
        </tran:outbound-properties>
        <tran:provider-specific xsi:type="http:HttpEndPointConfiguration">
            <http:outbound-properties>
                <http:request-method>POST</http:request-method>
                <http:timeout>15</http:timeout>
                <http:connection-timeout>15</http:connection-timeout>
                <http:follow-redirects>false</http:follow-redirects>
                <http:chunked-streaming-mode>false</http:chunked-streaming-mode>
                <http:session-sctikiness enabled="false" session-id-name="JSESSIONID"/>
            </http:outbound-properties>
            <http:dispatch-policy>SBDefaultResponseWorkManager</http:dispatch-policy>
            <http:compression>
                <http:compression-support>false</http:compression-support>
            </http:compression>
        </tran:provider-specific>
    </con:endpointConfig>
</con:businessServiceEntry>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does your OSB traffic go through external proxy?

Comment: I can see your connection and read timeout is set to 15 seconds so it should never take 20+ seconds but you have also retries configured - can you check the receiving side received only one request? It might seem unconventional but while OSB is executing your request can you take a series of consecutive thread dumps and check what is your thread doing?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comments. I cannot check the remote service cause it doesn't own to me (it is a web service provided by an external company). I'm not an expert with this technology so I didn't understand the last part of your comment, but I've tried many different configurations for the BS, even the pipeline and the proxy server but it didn't work. The only difference was changing the "Use Chunked Streaming Mode" option, if it is set to true, the request takes more than 2 minutes, but if it is set to false, the request gets a response in 21 seconds.